# Requirements for obtaining a long-term UK visitor visa (2, 5, or 10 years)

Tags: uk, indian-citizens

I am a Indian resident but currently own shares and am one of the directors of a Limited company registered in UK. Now we would like to visit UK quite often for client meetings and sales-related activities and for the same reason we would like to have a long term Business Visa.

1. Firstly am I eligible for a long term Business Visa?
2. What are the documents that would be required to submit during the Visa
   Application?

Comment: @pnuts a long-term visa for frequent short visits is decidedly on topic ("visit ... quite often for client meetings...").  Gautam: it is my understanding that long-term visas will generally only be granted after the traveler shows "performance" (i.e., compliance) with a number of "normal" (i.e., not long-term) visas.  I do not know what that number is.

Comment: @GayotFow does one not need to pay more for a long-term application?

Comment: For the trigger-happy close voters: this person is not asking about a long-stay visa, but a long-term one.  In other words, it is a Standard Visitor Visa that is valid for 2, 5, or 10 years.  Such a visa does not authorize long-term stays; it is for someone who makes many short-term visits.  See the details at the bottom of https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview.

Comment: You have a highly accurate and well-written answer to your question. Please extend the person the courtesy of accepting his answer. Read this for more info about the way the site works http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 6):

I was planning to leave this for someone else to answer, but it looks like the question may be closed by people who misunderstand it.

Our resident expert on UK immigration matters, [Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), has responded to a comment in which I said:

> long-term visas will generally only be granted after the traveler shows "performance" (i.e., compliance) with a number of "normal" (i.e., not long-term) visas. I do not know what that number is.

His response:

> @phoog this is right. the actual criteria that you do not know is classified and there's no reason to know it. I don't know it either. But thinking along the lines of 5 - 7 visitor visas jives with personal experience. Nobody gets to see what's classified. You should promote your comment.

He later added:

> In addition to phoog's comment, you do nothing special other than tick the long-term box. If they think you qualify they will issue it. Otherwise they will not issue it, there are no special documents to add and there is nothing extra to do except tick the box.

The advice, then, seems to be that you request a long-term visa by ticking the box.  To maintain your credibility, your application should presumably include a brief description of the circumstances that prompt you to ask for a long-term visa.

You should also consider it likely that you will be given a normal short-term visitor visa instead of a long term one, unless you have already held a number of short-term visitor visas.  If this happens, you should continue to ask for long-term visas in your subsequent applications, and it is likely that you will eventually be successful.