# Long-term UK visit visa

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, long-term

My wife and I completed our post-graduation studies in the UK in 2013 and since then we've visited the UK almost every year to catch up with friends and be in London for a couple of days to relive the times.

Now, as a result, we already have 1 student visa and 3 visitor visas (6 months each) for the UK. We are contemplating applying for a long-term visa (like 5 or 10 years) for convenience.

We have to travel to another city where VFS is located every time just to get a visa. The only concern is the huge amount that we need to pay without assurance, So would it be advisable to go for a long-term visa?

Comment: What is your citizenship and how long did you stay in the U.K. on your 3 previous visitor visas?

Comment: My citizenship is India and in the past 3 visitor visas, we usually stay for 4-5 days.

Comment: My first UK visa was a five year visa, but then I was a permanent resident of the USA so maybe my profile is different from yours. The second time I applied for ten years and only got 5 years. Because of the significantly higher cost of the 5 and 10 year visas I will not advise you to apply for those until you visit the UK  a few more times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer [Requirements for obtaining a long-term UK visitor visa (2, 5, or 10 years)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86685/requirements-for-obtaining-a-long-term-uk-visitor-visa-2-5-or-10-years) indicates that you may need more than a performance history of 3 short term visit visas. The only way to find out is to apply, weighing up the potential benefits if you’re successful vs the extra cost if not - perhaps applying for a 2 year visa first would improve your chances (you could probably squeeze in several visits over the period to make it cost-effective, if you timed your application carefully)