# Long term visitor visa (2 years) for company director without previous "performance"

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, business-travel, long-term

The director of our company wants to apply for a long term business visa to attend client meetings and negotiations. What are the chances he will be granted a 2 year long-term visitor visa if this is his first time applying for a UK standard visitor visa?

I remember reading a number of times that UKVI tends to look for "performance" in relation to 6 month visitor visas when making these kind of decisions.

Comment: You typically learn to crawl before you walk. That is how visa officers see these things.

Comment: We don't know. And what difference would our opinions make? Apply for a visa. He gets what he gets. If it's two years, great. If it's not, he'll have to apply again when that one expires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty slim unless he has a strong travel history to comparable destinations (Schengen, US, Canada, for example). See [Requirements for obtaining a long-term UK visitor visa (2, 5, or 10 years)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86685/requirements-for-obtaining-a-long-term-uk-visitor-visa-2-5-or-10-years)

As stated in the answer to the linked question, if he applies for a long-term Standard visitor visa but does not qualify, the ECO should grant the 6 month visitor visa providing he qualifies for it. The key differences are a compliant travel history to the UK and a credible reason for needing to visit regularly over a longer period.  A long-term Standard visit visa doesn’t change, for example, the permitted activities or the rule around frequency of visits/time being spent in the UK.

Comment: Would his visa application be refused outright or would he be issued a 6-month visitor visa?