# Is there a UK long-term multiple-visit visa?

Tags: visas, uk, nigerian-citizens

My younger sister is in the United Kingdom on a study visa. Can I apply for a long-term visit visa so I can be visiting often, as a first-timer? Like 2 - 5 years for instance?

Comment: Also see [Requirements for obtaining a long-term UK visitor visa (2, 5, or 10 years)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/86685/19400) -- basically you can apply for a long-term multiple-entry visa, but the application fee is rather higher and you're likely to get a shorter-term visa on the first few tries, in which case you will have spent much more money than you needed to.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/apply-standard-visitor-visa : a five year visa costs £771 while a six-month visa is £115.  It would only make sense if you go twice a year, but even then if your two annual visits are within six months of each other, e.g. every spring and every summer, then you could do that with five six-month visas.  And there's still the risk of paying £771 and ending up with a six-month visa.

Comment: Define ‘so I can be visiting *often*’. A visit pattern that makes it seem like you’re trying to live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK your main home, will be a red flag pretty quickly.